# How to get coordinates in R from kml file using st_read

Tags: r, kml, r-sf

I'm working with r and i'm trying to get from a KML file the geographic coordinates (lat and long). I'm using a KML file that i created in Google Earth and i get the coordinates in right way using `st_read()` from `sf package` in the next code:

```
Google_earth_kml <- st_read("prueba_direcciones_google_earth.kml")
```

The thing is that i get the next table:

```
Name                                                         description                             Geometry
store 1                   address: Barros Luco 2058<br>RUT: 08.180.861-9          c(-71.6132, -33.5985683, 0)
store 2   address: AVENIDA DOMINGO SANTA MARIA 1789<br>RUT: 76.585.397-4       c(-70.6639313, -33.4155609, 0)
```

And i want to get a table like:

```
Name                             address          Rut        long         lat
store 1                 Barros Luco 2058 08.180.861-9    -71.6132 -33.5985683
store 2 AVENIDA DOMINGO SANTA MARIA 1789 76.585.397-4 -70.6639313 -33.4155609
```

This is just a little part of my data. I know that maybe you will need the KML file but for reasons of politics and privacy i cant share it.

I wonder if someone can give me an opinion or other point of view.
Any help will be grateful thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `st_coordinates()` for this.

For the data, I just found an example KML file with point geometries online. I recommend trying that when you have data you are unable to share in the future.

**Data**

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

sample_KML <- "https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML/raw/master/sample/example.kml"

KML_sf <- st_read(sample_KML) %>% 
  slice(1:4) # keep only the first 4 rows. The 5th row is a polygon

KML_sf

Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XYZ
bbox:           xmin: -122.6819 ymin: -22.90833 xmax: 28.97602 ymax: 64.13333
z_range:        zmin: 0 zmax: 0
CRS:            4326
            Name Description                       geometry
1       Portland                POINT Z (-122.6819 45.52 0)
2 Rio de Janeiro             POINT Z (-43.19639 -22.9083...
3       Istanbul              POINT Z (28.97602 41.01224 0)
4      Reykjavik             POINT Z (-21.93333 64.13333 0)
```

**Output**

```
output <- KML_sf %>% 
  mutate(long = st_coordinates(.)[,1],
         lat = st_coordinates(.)[,2])


output

Simple feature collection with 4 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XYZ
bbox:           xmin: -122.6819 ymin: -22.90833 xmax: 28.97602 ymax: 64.13333
z_range:        zmin: 0 zmax: 0
CRS:            4326
            Name Description                       geometry       long       lat
1       Portland                POINT Z (-122.6819 45.52 0) -122.68194  45.52000
2 Rio de Janeiro             POINT Z (-43.19639 -22.9083...  -43.19639 -22.90833
3       Istanbul              POINT Z (28.97602 41.01224 0)   28.97602  41.01224
4      Reykjavik             POINT Z (-21.93333 64.13333 0)  -21.93333  64.13333
```

---

And if you want to get rid of the geometry column:

```
output %>% st_drop_geometry()

            Name Description       long       lat
1       Portland             -122.68194  45.52000
2 Rio de Janeiro              -43.19639 -22.90833
3       Istanbul               28.97602  41.01224
4      Reykjavik              -21.93333  64.13333
```

Comment: neat although calculating `st_coordinates(.)` twice does seem a little inefficient :)

Comment: very good point. sometimes I get fixated on just making a single piping operation. for a larger dataset, probably makes sense to make an intermediate object.

Comment: Yeah guess you could do an intermediate or just cbind the columns and rename them after. Either way its not as elegant so can see the appeal!